# I sent bitcoin to im sure was correct. I've sent before, its correct, this time he says it failed due to lock. Used cashapp to send to his wallet code

Tags: fraud, lost-transactions

I used cashapp to send btc to a wallet I've sent to before he says it failed and should be back. Cashapp can't help
The code I sent wallet to is:
bc1qne24j4v09t9lpyg6vttr3aamn7jmv6e2zegtw4.
[image: pic of transaction failure]

[image: img of wallet i sent it to from cashapp]

Can someone tell me if I'm being ripped off? Or why I can't get any help from cashapp? What do I do?
Did I get ripped off?

Answer (score 1):

See any blockchain explorer.

For example https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1qne24j4v09t9lpyg6vttr3aamn7jmv6e2zegtw4

[image: explorer shows 0.0142487 transaction is confirmed]

...

[image: 173 confirmations]

The transaction for that amount is confirmed. Anyone saying otherwise is either mistaken or telling lies in order to deceive you.

There is no such thing as a Bitcoin transaction failing "due to lock".

---

Some notes

- what you call a "wallet code" is more normally called a Bitcoin *address*. A Bitcoin wallet normally has many addresses and most wallets create a new address for every transaction.
- The transaction which paid 0.0142487 to bc1qne...zegtw4 also paid money to 198 others - this is normal behaviour for a business that provides custodial accounts, it is batching together payments for its customers in order to save on transaction fees.